# Deciding addition or updation

Tags: java, mysql

I need to add a record if already a record with the primary key doesn't exist; otherwise existing record is to be updated. For this I am querying the db with the primary key. If no record exist, I am adding; otherwise updating. I am coding this in java using raw JDBC.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using hibernate ?? or JDBC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. insert … select … where not exist
2. INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ON duplicate KEY UPDATE id = id
3. REPLACE INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...

Answer (score 2):

The most soft way to do this is to use special query [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query in My Sql. It is much more effective than check is conflict exist on the application side.

Code snippet for example:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=?;"
    );
    int paramIndex = 1;
    statement.setInt(parameterIndex++, primaryKeyValue);
    statement.setInt(parameterIndex++, secondValue);
    statement.setInt(parameterIndex++, thirdValue);
    statement.setInt(parameterIndex++, thirdValue);
    int updatedCount = statement.executeUpdate();
} finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) which takes the same syntax as `INSERT` but removes the old entry when the primary key already exists before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and the most general way is to count the record before insert/update.

Pseudo Code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as recordCount FROM mytable WHERE keyField = ?
if (recordCount > 0) {
   UPDATE mytable SET value1=? WHERE keyField = ?
} else {
   INSERT INTO mytable (keyField, value1) VALUES (?, ?)
}
```